# Im trying to search for data in a pivottable and display in a msgbox

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

So, I have an Accounting Sheet in which names are entered on a daily basis. I am trying to write some VBA to search those names, one by one after they are typed in another sheet which is an Outstandings Payment Sheet. There is a datewise list of all outstanding payments in that sheet and also a Pivottable for the same data. I am now being able to extract the outstanding payment but I am encountering an error when the name that is searched is not there in the outstandings sheet. I am a novice at VBA and all that I have written so far is by looking at help, forums, copy pasting code and some expirementation.

> application defined or object defined error - 1004

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Sheets("Accounts").Range("B4:B1000")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then

    ElseIf IsEmpty(Target.Address) Then

    Else
        MsgBox Target.Value
        Worksheets("OutstandingAndDeposits").Activate
        'Updating Table in Outstandings Sheet
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").PivotCache.Refresh

        Dim search_value As Variant                                           
        ' Get PivotData for the outstandings.
        ' the 1004 error occurs on the next line
        search_value = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target)
        MsgBox search_value
        Worksheets("Accounts").Activate
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Its an application defined or object defined error - 1004. The line is this one - search_value = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target)

Comment: Did you try to use `.GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target.Value)` with `Target.Value` instead of just `Target`?

Comment: The problem doesn't come in finding the correct value. It occurs when the search term is not there. For example, if the outstanding list has the name of person A and I search person A, i get his outstanding amount. But if I search for person B and his name is not there in the list, then I get the 1004 error

Comment: Try this `If Not ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target.Value) Is Nothing Then search_value = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target.Value).Value`

Comment: Nope, didnt work. I added that line in place of the error line "search_value = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target)", above the msgbox search_value line.  I still got the error. Error 1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this part of code:

```
search_value = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target)
MsgBox search_value
```

**Edited** With this one:

```
Dim search_value As Range
' try to assign to variable
On Error Resume Next
' in case there is nothing - there will be an error
Set search_value = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableOutstandings").GetPivotData("Amount", "Customer", Target)
On Error GoTo 0

' if value found - it is assigned to variable
' error comes in the next line. Object required error
If Not search_value Is Nothing Then
    ' show value
    MsgBox search_value
End If
```

See how it works
[image: how it works]

Comment: Getting an error here as well. Run Time error 424 - Object required. I am editing the place the error is coming. It comes in the line of - If not search_value is nothing then

Comment: @SahilDoshi Check the latest edit - you have to declare `Dim search_value As Range`, because `.GetPivotData` method [returns a Range object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.getpivotdata).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!